# How to add placeholders in or near the input fields in django models

Tags: python, django

I am trying to build a blog app in Django. The problem is that i am not able to mention any thing near the input field.

For example

There is an image field and i want mention "Only upload images of size 300px x 250px" near it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Could you show some html code?

Comment: Are you creating your own form or using the django form.Modelform to automatically create a form based on your model?

Comment: actually i am trying to put this on the admin page only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First install pillow, pip install Pillow, then modify your model as below

```
from django.db import models

from PIL import Image


class Yourmodelname(models.Model):

    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='profile_pics', help_text = 'upload image of 250*300')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.user.username} Profile'

    def save(self):
        super().save()

        img = Image.open(self.image.path)

        if img.height > 300 or img.width > 300:
            output_size = (300, 300)
            img.thumbnail(output_size)
            img.save(self.image.path)
```

Whatever be the user input image size it save in database as 300 * 300 image.